# Adjusted Options (Long Calls) on Expiry

Tags: call-options

I bought Long Calls (options) almost a year back.  This trade was made in 2019:

CHK210115C3.5
Strike price $3.5
Underlying symbol:CHK
Expiry: Jan 15 '21

After CHK underwent a 1:200 reverse split two months ago,  my options were adjusted to:

CHK1210115C3.5
Strike price $3.5 (remained same)
Underlying symbol: CHK vs CHK1 (extra one after CHK)??
Expiry: Jan 15 '21 ADJ (ADJ word meaning adjusted)
The bid price on these these adjusted options is zero and there is no trading in them, even if I put 1 cents order.

Questions:

1. After adjustment, should I treat CHK1 as a different symbol than CHK? If so, it doesn't show as a valid symbol when I try to look up.
2. Currently, CHK is trading at $15. Will my calls be ITM on expiry if price stays like this? What will happen on expiry date if I don't act? Is there a chance of getting options exercised and stocks assigned to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After adjustment, should I treat CHK1 as a different symbol than CHK?

Yes - you effectively have an option on a synthetic stock that is worth (per share) 1/200 of the "current" CHK share.

> Currently, CHK is trading at $15. Will my calls be ITM on expiry if price stays like this?

No - your options are equivalent to a call on the "new" CHK with a strike of $700 (200 * $3.5) So the stock would have to rally nearly 50X for your option to be in-the-money.

> What will happen on expiry date if I don't act?

Nothing - your option will expire worthless. You've already incurred your cost via the premium you paid.

There are no bids on your option because there is virtually zero chance that the options will be in-the-money.

Comment: Reverse splits leave the old options chain dead in the water with pretty high frequency. In most cases it's best to manage them before the reverse split. Splits also have a negative impact on options volume for the old chain, but in those cases you're more likely to have intrinsic value so they are not as bad as reverse splits in regards to options liquidity.

Answer (score 2):

When options are adjusted due to a split, a "1" is added to the option root symbol.  It is a new security.  If you are using a tax accounting program, you will have to force the pairing (or adjust the original symbol).

CHK1 is a valid symbol and its options can be looked up.  How you look it up depends on the web site or broker that you are using.  In some cases, you have to specify that you want to see adjusted options as well.

As @D Stanley explained, the your adjusted option is equivalent to a call with a strike price of $700 (200 * $3.5) so the stock would have to rally nearly 50X for your option to be in-the-money.  While that is near impossible, if that were to occur, if your calls were ITM at expiration, normally you would be automatically exercised by the OCC and you would have to buy the shares.

However, that's not the case here, an unusual circumstance.  Because it was a 1:200 reverse split, the end result was a contract for 1/2 a share.  Because of that, the contract has been converted to cash-in-lieu.  Here is a cut and paste of the OCC memo. I can't provide the link because I am registed with the OCC and the web address displays my name.  If you want to see it, Google "OCC CHK adjust option":

> OCC has been informed that a price of $33.128 per whole CHK share will be used to determine the cash
> in lieu amount. Accordingly, the cash in lieu amount is:

> 0.5 x $33.128 = $16.56 per CHK1 and CHK2D/CHK2I/CHK2J/CHK2K Contract

> Now that the exact cash in lieu amount has been determined, OCC will require Put exercisers and Call assignees, during the period of April 15, 2020 through April 22, 2020, to deliver the appropriate cash
> amount.

> Terms of the CHK1 options and CHK2D/CHK2I/CHK2J/CHK2K futures are as follows:

> New Deliverable Per Contract: $16.56 Cash (0.5 x $33.128)

---

Non sequitur to the powers that be: Has Stack programming changed the ability to see the preview of an answer before posting?

Comment: re: your last comment - I still see a preview for my answers, but you should post a question on https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/ and see if you get any diagnostic help there.

Comment: Also - good catch on the cash-in-lieu - I did not consider that angle.

Comment: I run two old computers and one had a hard drive crash last week.  The newly purchased one that I'm on now for a day offers preview  and lets me make comments but the older one that I was using all along stopped doing that yesterday.  Given that, I think that things are screwy on my end (the old compter).  If I can't figure it out, I'll use the meta link which I thank you for.

Comment: Initially, the cash-in-lieu didn't register and I couldn't make sense of the option adjustment.  While there have probably been many such option adjustments, in decades of doing this, I've never seen one before like this.  Anyway, the OP should have a better idea of this from our explanations.

Comment: So, wait. Even though these options won't expire until January 2021, OCC has *already* set the cash-in-lieu amount to $16.56 per contract, regardless of what happens to the stock price in the meantime? And, therefore, a call option with a strike price of $3.50 (meaning $350 per contract) is *guaranteed* to be worthless, even if the stock price goes to the moon before expiry?

Comment: @Tanner Swett - I agree with you, it's a strange adjustment.  Given that the OCC adjustment bulletin says that the "New Deliverable Per Contract: $16.56 Cash (0.5 x $33.128)", what other interpretation can there be?  Normally, when there's an uneven split that results in cash and a fractional share, you get cash-in-lieu for the fractional share.  So I think that's the gist of it here.  Doesn't seem fair. Fairness would have been jacking up the strike price thereby  allowing for the rare possibility of the stock going to the moon.

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected it to be something like "New deliverable per contract: 0.5 times the last closing price on or before the expiry date of the contract". But I looked at the memo myself, and it does seem to be saying that the cash-in-lieu amount has been set at $16.56 regardless of expiry date of the contract.

Comment: Thank you, all who answered my question. Trying to understand.the term "cash-in-lieu".  What exactly is it in the context of my adjusted options?

Comment: If a reverse split results in ending up with a fractional number of shares, companies often give cash-in-lieu for the  fractional shares. For example, you own 100 shares and there's a 1:3 reverse split.  Your position  becomes 33-1/3 shares and you end up with 33 shares and cash-in-lieu for 1/3 of a share.